# the more DVDs at the same time , the slower the burning!

Tags: dvd, performance, burning, nero

I'm using nero to burn multiple DVDs at the same time.
When I burn 1 DVD at one time it takes about 8 minutes to finish,
but when I try to burn 4 DVDs at the same time, it takes about 40 minutess!

Why does it take so long to burn multi DVDs at the same time?

I don't have any problem with hardware because when I'm burning DVDs, less than 20% of my CPU & RAM are in use.

I'm using one of my DVD writers as a source and other fours as DVD writer. I do not use my HD as a source. by the way i made some changes in nero and make the speed faster. (about 20 mins per 4 DVDs) the changes which i did are:

1. I changed "error corection" from slow and safe to fast and unsafe
2. i clicked the button "ignore reading errors

Are there any other ways to boost my burning speed?

Answer (score 12):

Chances are, you're maxing out your hard drive's [throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Throughput).  The hard drive can only spit out so much data per unit time.

**Edit:**  In response to your answer wherein you state that you are reading from one DVD drive and burning to several others, I suggest that you copy your source DVD to your hard drive.  This will be faster in the long run, especially if you are making more than one batch of four DVDs.

Comment: Yep, the HD is one of the slowest parts of a computer.  I agree, you are most likely maxing out your hard drive's throughput.

Comment: And to take this one step further, you'd likely see even better results if you have multiple hard drives to act as sources. i.e., If you could put the source rip on *two* hard drives and have each feed the source to two burners (each), you'd probably likely see better performance still. Ultimately, a 1:1 would likely yield optimal results.

Answer (score 4):

If you're currently copying from one optical drive (source) to many others (destination), you should see a hefty speed increase by first copying the source disc to your hard drive.  HDs are slow, but they're faster than optical drives by a long shot.

Your workflow should be:

1. Create an ISO copy of the disc to be copied on the hard drive.
2. Burn the ISO to your multiple destinations.

I've never played with 1-to-many DVD burning, so I don't know that your burning software will support a source on the hard drive.  But your results will no longer depend on the source DVD reader, and you get the chance to check your ISO copy for errors and correct them before burning.